# How to read a file in the following format

Tags: r, csv, file-format, read.csv

I have many files that I want to read. The format of the files are exactly as shown below.

I tried many package formats to read this and none of them seem to work. The lines that start with "-" should be skipped. There are about 102 columns in the files but I am showing only a few. The lines that start with "-" are actually in the 1st, 3rd and last rows.

The files are in the following format

```
------------------------------------------------
|Delivery |Created by |Time    |Created on|SDst|
------------------------------------------------
|84181375 |BATCHJOBMGR|19:33:47|01/05/2017|    |
|84181376 |BATCHJOBMGR|19:33:47|01/05/2017|    |
------------------------------------------------
```

I tried the following:

using read.table

```
temp <- read.delim(file="LIKP_01012016_01312016.txt", header=TRUE, 
                   stringsAsFactors=FALSE, 
                   strip.white=TRUE, sep="|", skip = 1, comment.char = "-")
```

using data.table

```
temp <- fread(input="LIKP_01012017_01312017.txt",  
              stringsAsFactors=FALSE, strip.white=TRUE, 
              sep="|",quote = "-", skip=1)
```

Obviously I am not doing something right. Could you help me with the reading of these files?

Thanks in advance.

Satish

Comment: Files separated by `|` are called PSV (pipe-separated value), similar to CSV or TSV (tab-separated). And the `------------------` lines we just ignore. Might do one preprocessing pass to remove them. Lines 1-3 are your header, but only line 2 is meaningful.

Answer (score 5):

**1)** In the sample data the only minus signs are in dashed lines. If that is also true for your real data then the following should work.  Replace `text = Lines` with `"LIKP_01012016_01312016.txt"` .  Note that `comment.char = "-"` causes any line with a minus to have that minus and everything after it on its line to be ignored effectively turning the lines of minuses into blank lines.

```
read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, sep = "|", as.is = TRUE, 
        comment.char = "-", check.names = FALSE, strip.white = TRUE)[2:6]
```

giving:

```
  Delivery  Created by     Time Created on SDst
1 84181375 BATCHJOBMGR 19:33:47 01/05/2017   NA
2 84181376 BATCHJOBMGR 19:33:47 01/05/2017   NA
```

**2** If you do have minus signs in the data then just skip the first line, use `fill = TRUE` and remove the first and last rows (which are the remaining ones with all minus signs).

```
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, sep = "|", as.is = TRUE, 
        skip = 1, fill = TRUE, check.names = FALSE, strip.white = TRUE)[2:6]
n <- nrow(DF)
DF <- DF[-c(1, n), ]
```

**Note:**  The input for the code above is:

```
Lines <- "------------------------------------------------
|Delivery |Created by |Time    |Created on|SDst|
------------------------------------------------
|84181375 |BATCHJOBMGR|19:33:47|01/05/2017|    |
|84181376 |BATCHJOBMGR|19:33:47|01/05/2017|    |
------------------------------------------------"
```

Comment: Maybe explain the `comment.char` trick and why that really saves the day here +1.

Comment: Hello Mr. Grothendieck: Thanks for your suggestions. My files are pretty large > 90 MB each and about 25 of them. So, I am wondering how I can follow your suggestion? Thanks, Satish

Comment: Easiest would just be to try it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `system()` command to correct each of input files. Following is for Linux using `sed` utility. All lines starting with `-` are deleted (`sed '/^-/d'`). In addition, all leading and trailing pipe (`|`) characters are also removed (`sed 's/^|//'` and `sed 's/|$//'`). The output can be saved to a temporary file which can be read with usual `read.csv` command, specifying the separator as `|`:

```
> system("cat LIKP_01012016_01312016.txt | sed '/^-/d' | sed 's/^|//' | sed 's/|$//' > temp.csv")
> dd = read.csv('temp.csv', na.strings='', sep="|")
> dd
  Delivery  Created.by     Time Created.on SDst
1 84181375 BATCHJOBMGR 19:33:47 01/05/2017   NA
2 84181376 BATCHJOBMGR 19:33:47 01/05/2017   NA
```

Above can be put in a `for` loop to convert and read all files one by one.

Comment: the OP is in a _fully feature complete programming language_ with the capabilities of `sed` baked in. This makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Different approach:

```
con <- file('path/to/file.txt')

d <- readLines(con)

d <- read.delim(textConnection(d[!grepl("-", d)]), sep = '|')[2:6]
```